# Is there a way to wait or pause until a subview is released before ending the function?

Tags: ios, viewcontroller

In one of my functions, from a button press,  I am adding a subview, then typing text to a textview in that subview. I want to then take that text back to the original function and save it to a variable. The problem is that I have multiple buttons that all use this subview but with different variables, so it can't just run the same function for all of them after it's released.

```
main view controller    
-(IBAction)Button1Pressed:(id)sender{
   NSString *TempString;

   TextEditViewController* TextViewController = [[TextEditViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TextEditViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
   [self.view addSubview:TextViewController.view];

   /* wait for subview to be released */

   SpecificString = TempString;
}

-(IBAction)Button2Pressed:(id)sender{
   NSString *TempString;

   TextEditViewController* TextViewController = [[TextEditViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TextEditViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
   [self.view addSubview:TextViewController.view];

   /* wait for subview to be released */

   DifferentSpecificString = TempString;
}

New view controller
-(IBAction)doneButtonPressed:(id)sender{
   TempString = textView.text;
   [self.view removeFromSuperview];
   [self.view release]; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what the magic of *delegates* is best for.

```
- (void) setSomeString: (NSString *) withThisString
{
   // buttonPressed can be an instance variable,
   // or you can do this some other way
   switch(buttonPressed)
   {
       case 1 :
           // you should always name variables and methods
           // with lower case letters, that's the
           // Objective C standard
           specificString = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: withThisString];
       case 2:
           // doing an alloc & init here makes a retained copy
           // of the string passed in via the delegate method
           differentSpecificString = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: withThisString];
   }
}

- (IBAction) button1Pressed: (id) sender
{
    buttonPressed = 1;

    TextEditViewController* textViewController = [[TextEditViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TextEditViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    textViewController.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:textViewController.view];
}

- (IBAction) button2Pressed: (id) sender
{
    buttonPressed = 2;

    TextEditViewController* textViewController = [[TextEditViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TextEditViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    textViewController.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:textViewController.view];    
}
```

You also need to declare your delegate protocol in your main view controller's .h (interface) file.  [Here's a tutorial that explains this concept a bit more for you](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/objective-c/the-basics-of-protocols-and-delegates.html).

I hope this helps you out!

Comment: That could work I guess, although I have at least 50 buttons so it would be a lot of cases. Thanks! Thank you for the tutorial too, I was a little confused about delegates in the first place.